# Error when attempting to render multiple ReactElements by mapping through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am currently looking to render multiple elements within a class by looping through an array that has been passed via props from the Owner of this component. Here is an an example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.styles.container}>
            {this.props.matchup
                ? this.renderMatchupWithTeams(this.props.matchup)
                : this.renderDefaultMatchup()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and then...

```
renderMatchupWithTeams(matchup) {
    console.log('renderMatchupWithTeams', matchup);
    return matchup.map(team => {
        console.log(`team: ${team.name}, seed: ${team.seed}`);
        return (
            <Team name="UCLA"
                      seed={matchup.seed}/>
        )
    });
};
```

The logs were included to highlight the fact that the values are returning as expected in the logs, but the Team component is not.

Any ideas as to why the component is not rendering as expected? Please note that forEach yields the same result as map in this instance.

** code has been updated to reflect the correct answer **

Comment: Your `renderMatchupWithTeams` function returns undefined. You should read about how `Array#map` works. If you `return matchup.map` things will start working.

Answer (score 2):

Total oversight on my part. Of course, when .map() is applied to an array, a new array is **projected**. Thus, we must **return** matchups.map in order to get the new value (array) that is created (projected).

Comment: Would you attach the fixed code and accept this answer? This way it may help future visitors.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the original code without editing the rest of your question; now it looks like you were using working code, and so your problem makes no sense. Maybe leave the original code as it was, and then add a footnote with a little message that says you realized your mistake and append the working code with an explanation, or just put the working code in this answer and leave the original question unchanged. (Accepting this answer like suggested by Pavlo would be good too)